# How To remove Extra Line spacing between rows in CollectionView IOS?

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, iphone, xamarin

[image]

I want to shift the cells up by removing the extra white space on top of the cells, as cells have different heights. I am using flow layout and I implemented delegate methods of flowlayout as well for line and item spacing.

Here is my code

```
public partial class TestVc : UIViewController
{    
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        string[] words = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", 
            "six seven eight", "nine ten eleven twelve thirteen",
            "the quick brown fox"};

        grid.DataSource = new MyDS(words);
        grid.Delegate = new FlowLayoutDelegate(words);
        var layout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout();
    }
}

public class MyDS : UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    string[] words;

    public MyDS(string[] _words)
    {
        words = _words;
    }

    public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, 
        NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {    
        UICollectionViewCell cell = collectionView
            .DequeueReusableCell("MyCellTest", indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell;
        MyCellTest demoCell = cell as MyCellTest;

        return cell;
    }

    public override nint GetItemsCount(UICollectionView collectionView, 
        nint section)
    {
        return words.Length;
    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections(UICollectionView collectionView)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

class FlowLayoutDelegate : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    string[] items;

    public FlowLayoutDelegate(string[] items)
    {
        this.items = items;    
    }

    public override nfloat GetMinimumInteritemSpacingForSection(
        UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, nint section)
    {
        return 5;
    }

    public override nfloat GetMinimumLineSpacingForSection(
        UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, nint section)
    {
        return 5;
    }

    public override CoreGraphics.CGSize GetSizeForItem(UICollectionView collectionView, 
        UICollectionViewLayout layout, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        int numOfcoll = 2;
        int margans = 40;

        if (indexPath.Row == 0)
        {
            return new CGSize((collectionView.Bounds.Width - margans) / numOfcoll, 200);
        }
        else
        {
            return new CGSize((collectionView.Bounds.Width - margans) / numOfcoll, 73);
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly tell me any solution without any library. I already posted a question but didn't receive an answer from Xamarin community, so I am adding the IOS community in it as its C# code but don't worry suggest me solution in objective c, i will implement it in C# Xamarin by my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate hight of each image and set sizeofcell according to image's size.

You can check this tutorial.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/164608/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest-2

Comment: Sir but i am giving height hardcoded the issue is that cell are not adjusting them accordingly..